# Jumper in Java?

Tags: java, goto

Is there any syntax that allows you to jump from one line to the other?

example:

```
System.out.println("line");
System.out.println("line2");
System.out.println("line3");
System.out.println("line4");

//goto line2 or something like that??
```

Comment: You can create methods, each of them containing a single line and invoke them whenever you want to simulate `goto`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no `goto` statement, but there are several workarounds:

```
do {
    //do stuff
    if (condition) break; //this will jump--+
    //do stuff                           // |
} while (false);                         // |
// here <-----------------------------------+
```

and

```
int id = 0;
while (true) {
    switch (id) {
        case 0:
            //do stuff
            if (condition) {id = 3; break;} //jumps to case 3:
        case 1:
            if (condition) {id = 1; break;} //jumps to case 1:
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in a roundabout way, for example with a switch statement:

```
switch (lineNum) {
  case 1: System.out.println("line 1");
  case 2: System.out.println("line 2");
  case 3: System.out.println("line 3");
  case 4: System.out.println("line 4");
}
```

Now you must ensure `lineNum` has the appropriate value.

For any backward jumps you'll need a `do` or `while` loop.

Comment: Marko is cleverly exploiting the follow-through feature of java switch; e.g. if lineNum = 2 then cases 2, 3, 4 are all ran.

Answer (score 1):

Java *intentionally* does not support goto. This is to encourage (force) you to build the control flow using the proper conditional constructs.

In your example, the proper method would be a while-loop:

```
System.out.println("line");
while (true) {
    System.out.println("line2");
    System.out.println("line3");
    System.out.println("line4");
}
```

If you think about it, there is no code flow pattern that cannot be expressed without the need for goto (it may require to stray from personal ingrained habits). The only time you *may* want to use goto is to avoid code duplication. If you encounter such a case, restructuring the code into a separate method that can be called where needed is a much cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is no goto in Java although it is a reserved keyword.

A goto is considered a bad programming construct and, as such, was left out of Java.

Answer (score 0):

what exactly do you want to achieve? you could use labels as in http://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2008/06/25/tipjava-using-block-label-as-goto/, anyway using goto like statements could lead to spaghetti code

Comment: *Could*, yes. But only because a feature *could* lead to bad code, the feature isn't bad per se...

Comment: i agree, this subject could lead to further discutions of wheter gotos are useful or not but in my particulary experience with languages that allow goto expresions I can only see spaguetti code. And besides something like this could happen http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: Anything could happen at any time. But at probability rates of `1E-40` and below, I'll take the risk :-)